# Get values of dynamically created HTML controls

Tags: javascript, html, user-controls

I have created dynamic controls in HTML and I want to get the values of those dynamic controls through javascript.

Some thing like below *catogory1* and *catgory2* are my controls:

```
<select name=Category1 id=task1 onChange="SelectSubCatMtask(3);">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Task</option>
</select>

<select name=Category2 id=task2 onChange="SelectSubCatMtask(3);">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Task</option>
</select>
```

I wish to get the controls value in external .js file like below

```
document.mtask.Category0.value
```

where *mtask* is my form name and *Category0* is my control value.

I have used `alert(document.mtask.Category0.value)` and I can get the expected value. Now if I want to iterate I could not get it to work:

```
var step;
for (step = 0; step < 5; step++) 
{
    document.mtask.Category+step.value
}
```

Comment: if you want to traverse the `<select>` object, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just give the same class name to your selects and first iterate over them and get values of them.

```js
for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("selectBox").length;i++){
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("selectBox")[i].value)
}
```

```html
<select name=Category1 id=task1 class='selectBox'  onChange="SelectSubCatMtask(3);">
<option value="2" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Task</option>
</select>
<select name=Category2 id=task2 class='selectBox'  onChange="SelectSubCatMtask(3);">
<option value="1" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Task</option>
</select>
```